# How to filter Get-ADComputer output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My `Get-ADComputer` script gives too much information. I would like to shorten it out a little.

```
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input computer name'
$ManagedBy = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties ManagedBy |
             foreach { $_.ManagedBy }
Write-Output $ManagedBy
```

When I tried to run my scrip it gives this to output

```
CN=Last Name First Name ,OU=XX ,OU=XXX ,OU=XXX ,DC=XXX,DC=XXX
```

I would like to get only CN in the output (First name and Las Name).

Answer (score 2):

Your code returns the distinguished name of the computer's manager. You can use that DN to query the AD user object and obtain the desired properties from that (like `FullName`, or `DisplayName`, or the individual values `FirstName` and `LastName`).

```
Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties ManagedBy |
    Select-Object -Expand ManagedBy |
    Get-ADUser -Property FullName |
    Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have you looked at the objects properties?
These Properties are auto assigned to the variable, when created.

You can see them with:

$ManagedBy | Get-Member

You may well find that $ManagedBy.Name will give exactly what you want.

Further reading for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6